# Dealing with RGBA with decimal values

Tags: c#, regex, colors

I have a value: **RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.090)**

I need to paint this in a grid cell.

I have the following code so far:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(e.CellValue.ToString(), @"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)");

if (matches.Count == 4)
{
    Color.FromArgb(matches[4].Value, matches[0].Value, matches[1].Value, matches[2].Value);
}
```

Thing is, `Color.FromArgb` is dealing with `Int32` only. And as far as I've seen, all the functions under the `Color.` are `Int32` dealing. How do I manage precisions here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is:
Parse the parts using the regex you provided, use the parts to calculate an appropriate integer value based on a range of 0-255 and combine the parts to form the color.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)");
string colorData = "RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.090)";

var matches = regex.Matches(colorData);
int r = GetColorValue(matches[0].Value);
int g = GetColorValue(matches[1].Value);
int b = GetColorValue(matches[2].Value);
int a = GetColorValue(matches[3].Value);

var color = Color.FromArgb(a,r,g,b);


private static int GetColorValue(string match)
{
    return (int)Math.Round(double.Parse(match, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * 255);
}
```

Comment: And what can be the reverse process? I.e, From a System.Drawing.Color to four integers? I have this much as of now `      var c = BitConverter.GetBytes(GetColor().ToArgb());

      Alpha = c[0] ;
      Red = c[1];
      Green = c[2];
      Blue = c[3];  
    }`

Comment: or color.R, color.G, color.B etc, there are properties there to make this work

Comment: Yes, they are Bytes type. I want to scale back to the original Int32 with the precision RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.090)

Comment: Convert the byte to a double and divide by 255.0

Answer (score 1):

Color.FromArgb is using different value scale where values are in range betweeen 0 and 255.
I havent tested, but it should be somethign along those lines:

```
   public Color FromArgbFloat(float alpha, float r, float g, float b)
   {
      return Color.FromArgb((int)Math.Round(alpha*255), (int)Math.Round(r*255), (int)Math.Round(g*255), Math.Round(b*255);
   }
```

Comment: Same error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Are you sure that the error message says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'". It is strange because my code snippet is not using double at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Color.FromArgb` works with an `int` from 0 to 255, you can change your code to:

```
Color.FromArgb(Transform(matches[3].Value), Transform(matches[0].Value), Transform(matches[1].Value), Transform(matches[2].Value));

// ...

private int Transform(double value)
{
    return (int)Math.Round(value*255);
}
```

Comment: Good but I get an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Yes, there was a cast missing and the index 4 must be a 3. I fixed this.